# Trouble with streamlite.write() pandas dataframe does not show all information

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I'm using st.write() to display a dataframe with long strings in a column. When i display the dataframe with st.write(df) it does not show all info, here is an example:

Here is the code:

```
with st.container():
     st.write('<style>div[data-baseweb="table"] .cell {white-space: pre-wrap;}</style>', 
     unsafe_allow_html=True)
     st.dataframe(df_observaciones, width=1500, height=450)
```

[image]

I want to see all the info and include line breaks if necesary, any help will be good.

Comment: What info is missing? Do you have a [mcve]?

Comment: Here i made a new post addressing the situation, with a short example:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75471430/text-gets-truncated-while-using-streamlit-writedf

Comment: Why not [edit] the current one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy option is to use st.table(df), shows all the info.

- https://docs.streamlit.io/library/api-reference/data/st.table

  st.table(df)